# Pass URL parameters and props to Route's rendered component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In `react-router`, in order to access the URL parameters, you have to use the `component` prop of `<Route>`:

```
<Route path="/articles/:id" component={Article} />
//Then use the injected this.props.match.params.id to retrieve the id
```

And to pass props to a rendered component, you have to use the `render` prop of `<Route>`:

```
<Route path="/articles" render={() => <PageArticles width={200} />} />
```

But how do you do to pass the URL parameters and pass props to the rendered component at the same time?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The render prop's function has the route props in the signature:

```
<Route path="/articles" render{
  (routeParams) => <PageArticles routeParams={routeParams} width={200} />
}/>
```

You can see it in [this code snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/386yn58np1) i made